# Xamarin Forms IOS 16 Keyboard Hides on Tap Gesture

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When we updated the build to IOS 16 we noticed that when you click the SendMessage_Tapped the keyboard hides for a moment then reappears (due to EditorMessage.Focus() firing)  unlike previous builds IOS >=15 and Any Android version.

Front End Code

```
       <controls:KeyboardFloatFrame
            Grid.Row="3"
            Style="{StaticResource ChatInputBoxFrameStyle}"
            Focused="EditorArea_Focused"
            IsVisible="{Binding ShowKeyboardSection}">
            <pancakeview:PancakeView
                Style="{StaticResource ChatInputBoxPanCakeViewStyle}"
                Focused="EditorArea_Focused">
                <Grid x:Name="EditorContainerGrid"
                      Padding="{OnPlatform iOS='10,5,0,5'}"
                      Focused="EditorArea_Focused"
                      RowSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <controls:ChatEditor x:Name="EditorMessage"
                                         Grid.Column="0"
                                         Text="{Binding Message}"
                                         Focused="EditorMessage_Focused"
                                         Unfocused="EditorMessage_Unfocused" />

                    <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                          VerticalOptions="End"
                          IsVisible="false"
                          Padding="{OnPlatform iOS='0,0,0,10'}"
                          x:Name="SendIconGrid"
                          Opacity="{Binding SendButtonOpacity }"
                          HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                        <Image Source="send_icn"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"
                               VerticalOptions="End"
                               Margin="0">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                                      Tapped="SendMessage_Tapped" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                                  Tapped="SendMessage_Tapped" />
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <pancakeview:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="EditorFrameArea_Tapped" />
                </pancakeview:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
            </pancakeview:PancakeView>
        </controls:KeyboardFloatFrame>
```

Backend Code

```
              #region Event Handlers

        private void SendMessage_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            KeepFocusOnMessageEditor();
            _viewModel.SendMessage.Execute(sender);
        }

        private void EditorArea_Focused(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            KeepFocusOnMessageEditor();
        }

        private void EditorFrameArea_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            KeepFocusOnMessageEditor();
        }

        private void BodyGrid_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsIOS)
            {
                EditorMessage.Unfocus();
            }
        }

        private void EditorMessage_Focused(System.Object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            Constants.AndroidFlags.IgnoreFocusChanges = true;
            SendIconGrid.IsVisible = true;
        }

        private void EditorMessage_Unfocused(System.Object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            Constants.AndroidFlags.IgnoreFocusChanges = false;
            if (_viewModel.Message.IsBlank())
            {
                SendIconGrid.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        private void ScrollToMessage(ChatMessage message)
        {
            if (message != null && message.IsUnreadHeaderText && message.MessageStatus != Common.ChatMessageStatus.Read)
            {
                message.MessageStatus = Common.ChatMessageStatus.Read;
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ListViewChat.ScrollTo(message, ScrollToPosition.End, false));
            }
            else
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ListViewChat.ScrollTo(message, ScrollToPosition.End, false));
            }
        }

        private void KeepFocusOnMessageEditor()
        {

            if (IsIOS)
            {
                EditorMessage.Focus();
            } else {

                Constants.AndroidFlags.IgnoreFocusChanges = true;
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => EditorMessage.Focus());
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

I was expecting the for IOS 16 is act the same way as the other version where the keyboard doesn't hide when you click on the SendMessage_Tapped image. Just looking for a way to keep the keyboard up if the user click the icon.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new sample and used the entry instead of the `controls:ChatEditor` in your code. And I found that the keyboard is not always show when I clicked the imageview.

The keyboard will flash once when I clicked the image on the ios 15.4 and will be hiden and show on the ios 16.0. Actually, the default behavior should be  **the keyboard hides for a moment then reappears**.

Acording to the official document about [show and hide the keyboard in the native ios](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield#1652934), the keyboard's showing and hiding depend on the notification sent by the input view. When you click the image view, the input view lost focus and then got focused again. So the keyboard hides for a moment then reappears.

And there is an issue about [iOS 16 Keyboard Lagging](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254214165), you can see the keyboard hiden and reappeared on the iOS 16 is for the low reponse of the keyboard.

In addition, if you want to keep the keyboard on the screen, you need to custom a native input view and override the method about losing focus and sending [keyboardWillHideNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621606-keyboardwillhidenotification). It's a hard work.